# A question based on the kinetic theory of gases

Tags: thermodynamics, kinetic-theory, gas

An insulated container containing monoatomic gas of mass $m$ is moving with a velocity $v$. If the container is suddenly stopped find the change in the temperature of the gas.

I want to know why change in kinetic energy is $\frac{1}{2} m v^2$.

*Can you tell what's wrong in the following ideas?*

While considering the velocity for energy we must consider the relative velocity between container and gas.
Then let before stopping the container  relative speed was $v$ and after stopping change in speed.
Then the change in $K$ is $\frac{1}{2}m(v+v')^{2} -\frac{1}{2}mv^{2}$.

Comment: Why do you think that before stopping the container, there is relative velocity between the container and the gas? Gas molecules of course move relative to the container, but each molecule in different direction and with different speed. It is more likely the original question assumes macroscopic elements of the gas are at rest wrt the container. And what is $v'$?

Answer (score 1):

The atoms of the gas have kinetic energy due to their random motions (they could have rotational and vibrational energy as well, but since we know this is a monoatomic gas, we can ignore those contributions). This random component of the gas's kinetic energy is what we measure when we measure the gas's temperature.

However, when the container is moving with velocity $v$, the atoms of the gas also have a non-random component to their motion - they are all moving with the same velocity $v$ as the container. This non-random motion is superposed on top of their random motions. Since the total mass of gas in the container is $m$, the total kinetic energy due to this non-random motion is $\frac 1 2 mv^2$.

When the container stops moving, the kinetic energy $\frac 1 2 mv^2$ cannot just disappear. And because the container stops suddenly (which we can take to mean instantaneously) the container does no work on whatever is stopping it. Instead, the non-random kinetic energy of gas now increases the random component of the gas's kinetic energy. At a macroscopic level, we see this increase in the random component of kinetic energy as an increase in temperature.

Comment: "Instead, it increases the random component of the gas's kinetic energy." Some external agent, for example kinetic friction, did negative work bringing the container to a stop. That absorbs the kinetic energy of the container as a whole.

Comment: During deceleration there will be temperature gradients within the gas. The trailing part of the gas in the container does work (and cools) compressing the leading part of the gas (which warms) against the container wall. These gradients  even out when equilibrium is restored. There is no change in internal energy.

Comment: Container stopping instantaneously does not imply no work is done on the body stopping it. However, if the container has negligible mass compared to the gas, it has negligible kinetic energy and the work done is negligible.

Answer (score 1):

There is no change in the gas temperature after the container stops and internal equilibrium is restored.

Per the first law for a closed system

$$\Delta U=Q-W$$

For an ideal gas, any process,

$$\Delta U=nC_{v}\Delta T$$

Since the container is insulated, $Q=0$. If the container is rigid (cannot expand or contract), then boundary work $W=0$. The system is therefore isolated and so $\Delta U=0$ making $\Delta T=0$.

The velocity of the container as a whole has no effect on the temperature of the gas, which is determined only by the random kinetic energies of the gas molecules, not the kinetic energy of the gas as a whole.. The container lost kinetic energy due to some external agent that brought the container to a stop. That external agent absorbed the kinetic energy of the container.

Hope this helps.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151206/discussion-on-answer-by-bob-d-a-question-based-on-the-kinetic-theory-of-gases); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.